# Why show and hide Fragments with BottomNavigation view is not woking?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, fragmentmanager

I am working with `BottomNavigationView` and 5 fragments in it. I want to each fragment create only one time and doesn't recreate each time the user switch between them.

Because of that I am creating all the fragments and try to show and hide them in the fragment container.

This is my code:
(I write this code with this [help](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/issues/385#issuecomment-245116938) )

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private Fragment ideaFragment = IdeaFragment.newInstance();
  private Fragment articleFragment = ArticleFragment.newInstance();
  private Fragment videoFragment = VideoFragment.newInstance();
  private Fragment magFragment = MagFragment.newInstance();
  private Fragment mainListFragment = MainListFragment.newInstance();


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(view);


    btmNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);
    btmNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

    fm = ((FragmentActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager();

    MainPresenter mainPresenter = new MainPresenter((MainListContract.View) mainListFragment, appRepository);
    ArticlePresenter articlePresenter = new ArticlePresenter((ArticleContract.View) articleFragment, appRepository);
    IdeaPresenter ideaPresenter = new IdeaPresenter((IdeaContract.View) ideaFragment, appRepository);
    VideoPresenter videoPresenter = new VideoPresenter((VideoContract.View) videoFragment, appRepository);
    MagPresenter magPresenter = new MagPresenter((MagContract.View) magFragment, appRepository);


    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, magFragment, "5").commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, ideaFragment, "4").commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, videoFragment, "3").commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, articleFragment, "2").commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, mainListFragment, "1").commit();

  }

  //setting up bottom navigation menu
  BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

      //Fragment currentFragment = ((FragmentActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);


      switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.nav_home:

          if (active != mainListFragment)
            fm.beginTransaction().show(mainListFragment).commit();
          else
            fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(mainListFragment).commit();
          active = mainListFragment;


        case R.id.nav_article:

          if (active != articleFragment)
            fm.beginTransaction().show(articleFragment).commit();
          else
            fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(articleFragment).commit();
          active = articleFragment;


        case R.id.nav_video:

          if (active != videoFragment)
            fm.beginTransaction().show(videoFragment).commit();
          else
            fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(videoFragment).commit();
          active = videoFragment;


        case R.id.nav_idea:

          if (active != ideaFragment)
            fm.beginTransaction().show(ideaFragment).commit();
          else
            fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(ideaFragment).commit();
          active = ideaFragment;


        case R.id.nav_mag:

          if (active != magFragment)
            fm.beginTransaction().show(magFragment).commit();
          else
            fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(magFragment).commit();
          active = magFragment;

      }

      return true;
    }
  };
}
```

My problem is that `MainListFragment` will show when opening the application but when I try to go to other fragments nothing happens!
And  `MainListFragment` will not change!

Where am I wrong?

Thankyou for your answers.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, fragment doesn't hide and show another fragment.  How you solved it? Please shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

Leave only the main one with a `replace` instead of the `add` :

`fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, magFragment, "5").commit();`

and remove this from the `onCreate`

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, ideaFragment, "4").commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, videoFragment, "3").commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, articleFragment, "2").commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, mainListFragment, "1").commit();
```

then, in the on `onNavigationItemSelected` do the follow:

```
switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.nav_home:
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, magFragment, "5").commit();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_article:
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, articleFragment, "2").commit();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_video:
        fm.beginTransaction().replaceR.id.fragment_container, videoFragment, "3").commit();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_idea:
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, ideaFragment, "4").commit();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_mag:
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, mainListFragment, "1").commit();
        break;
}
```

Instantiating every fragment in the `onCreate` is the right way, in this way, you won't create another fragment everytime you switch. If you want to achieve that behavior you have to use something like this:

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MagPresenter((MagContract.View) magFragment, appRepository), "1").commit();
```

Comment: Thank you, But this is not what I want. In this way that you said when the user switches between fragments, that fragment will recreate again. But I want to create each fragment only once and after that resume it.

Comment: No, in this way the fragment are NOT recreated. The fragments are created only when the activity is created, then, the same fragments are used to switch between pages

Comment: But when I switch from fragment 1 to fragment 2, fragment 1 will execute `onDestroy` method and because of that, all received data in that fragment will destroy too.

Comment: I used `addToBackStack` in my code and added every fragment into the stack. like this : `fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, mainListFragment, "1")
            .addToBackStack("1")
            .commit();`
Now on destroy will not call but my data list will destroy any way.

Comment: reading the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) the onDestroy shouldn't be called when you use back stack, it should stop just before, in the onDestroyView, can you test it?

Comment: Fragments are recreating. OnCreate method calling everytime. Any other suggestions?